# Library comments like duolingo

Tags: android

I am searching some visual library to android to make comments (discussion) as a tree, like duolingo app or some way to do it beautiful.

I searched it through google, android-arsenal, github and stackoverflow without sucess.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: Not yet, sorry.

Comment: Did you get any message?